# What is the recurrence if the base case is O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, recurrence

We have to create an algorithm and find and solve its recurrence. Finding the recurrence has me stumped..

```
foo(A, C)
  if (C.Length = 0)
    Sum(A)
  else
    t = C.Pop()
    A.Push(t)
    foo(A,C)
    foo(A,C)
```

Initially A is empty and C.Length = n. I can't give the real algorithm because that's not allowed.

My instructor told me that I might try to use 2 variables. This is what I came up with:

```
T(n, i) = { n                if i =  0
            2*T(n, i-1) + C  if i != 0
```

I couldn't solve it, so I also tried to solve a recurrence with just one variable:

```
T(n) = { n0                  if n =  0
         2*T(n-1) + C        if n != 0
```

Where n0 is the initial value of n.

How do you form a recurrence from an algorithm where the complexity of the base case is O(n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let f(n) be the complexity if C is of size n. Let N be the original size of C.

Then f(0) = N and f(n) = 2 * f(n - 1) + c.

This has the solution f(n) = N * 2^n + (2^n - 1) * c, and so f(N) = O(N * 2^N).